# Extract text between two substrings using regular expression multiline in python

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract text between two substring or phrases using python using regular expression.

Sample text:

```
NAME – Testing set ADDRESS – 1470 ROAD CONTACT NUMBER - +91-44578558774 E-MAIL – test.side@gmail.com 


PROFESSIONAL PROFILE 

A petroleum graduate with professional experience in workover operation & Surface Well Testing operation and implementation of procedures and best practices following knowledge management processes. Seeking a role in oil and gas industry to develop engineering and management skills and apply new ideas to real life industry problem. 


PROFESSIONAL EXPERIENCE 

RIG (JUN 2014 – SEPT 2015)  

Performed various workover operations in SRP and ESP wells developed in Ahmedabad (ONGC Project) & Durgapur (ESSAR Project). My responsibilities as Roustabout on Rig was to perform:  Make pipe connection & Operate Tongs while running in and Pull out of Sucker rod & Tubings.

CORE COMPETENCIES: 

1. Well versed with varioussoftware for well testing (Wireless software). 2. Good Knowledge of MS-EXCEL, MS-Word.
```

What will the regex be for extracting all the text between **PROFESSIONAL PROFILE** and 
**CORE COMPETENCIES**?
I am not able to get the regex right.

Comment: Maybe: `PROFESSIONAL PROFILE([\s\S]+)CORE COMPETENCIES:` which puts it into group 1 (\1).  Best to post an attempt and ask for improvements or what you find is not working rather than just stating the task required ;o)

Comment: I tried the same expression, but didn't get the output. Apologies missed out on posting my attempt

Comment: I'll post an answer to show some code as it's too tricky to show in the comments

Answer (score 1):

To continue from the comments...Try this as a demo...

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'PROFESSIONAL PROFILE([\s\S]+)CORE COMPETENCIES:')

data = '''
NAME – Testing set ADDRESS – 1470 ROAD CONTACT NUMBER - +91-44578558774 E-MAIL – test.side@gmail.com 


PROFESSIONAL PROFILE 

A petroleum graduate with professional experience in workover operation & Surface Well Testing operation and implementation of procedures and best practices following knowledge management processes. Seeking a role in oil and gas industry to develop engineering and management skills and apply new ideas to real life industry problem. 


PROFESSIONAL EXPERIENCE 

RIG (JUN 2014 – SEPT 2015)  

Performed various workover operations in SRP and ESP wells developed in Ahmedabad (ONGC Project) & Durgapur (ESSAR Project). My responsibilities as Roustabout on Rig was to perform:  Make pipe connection & Operate Tongs while running in and Pull out of Sucker rod & Tubings.

CORE COMPETENCIES: 

1. Well versed with varioussoftware for well testing (Wireless software). 2. Good Knowledge of MS-EXCEL, MS-Word.

'''

#print(pattern.search(data)[1])
#I think the  is tripping the code up so consider...
print(pattern.search(data)[1].encode('utf8'))
```

Outputs:

```
A petroleum graduate with professional experience in workover operation & Surface Well Testing operation and implementation of procedures and best practices following knowledge management processes. Seeking a role in oil and gas industry to develop engineering and management skills and apply new ideas to real life industry problem. 


PROFESSIONAL EXPERIENCE 

RIG (JUN 2014 – SEPT 2015)  

Performed various workover operations in SRP and ESP wells developed in Ahmedabad (ONGC Project) & Durgapur (ESSAR Project). My responsibilities as Roustabout on Rig was to perform:  Make pipe connection & Operate Tongs while running in and Pull out of Sucker rod & Tubings.
```

Comment: Simple answer but works perfectly in my case... just wanted to upvote you as it solved what I thought was a complex issue... https://regex101.com/r/smxV0v/1